# My notification in TabBar it in the wrong place

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

[image: notification in Chats Tabbar]

I want my notification appear in Chats Tabbar but it appear in the wrong place (You can see it in picture above)

Here is my code in Chats Tabbar:

```
func refreshTabCounter() {

    var total: Int = 0

    for chat in chats {
        total += chat.unreadCount
    }

    let item = tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[0]
    item?.badgeValue = (total != 0) ? "\(total)" : nil

    UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = total
}
```

How I gonna fix it?

Comment: Because `items?[0]` gives you first item which is home and chat is second item at index 1.

Comment: OHHHH!!! I see it a stupid mistake. Thank you very much